# Find and replace duplicate rows with the newest data in a defined range using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Google sheet using columns A:M. Each day a new set of raw data (around 30 rows) is pasted on the next available row in column B manually. This raw data contains duplicate rows that have some updated column contents since the previous day. Column C contains the Job Number which is used to determine duplicates, and column A contains a sequential ID from 1 to n.

I need to create a function that finds duplicate rows based on column C, then uses the row with the largest Column A value to overwrite the data in the lowest Column A value so that the order of jobs numbers added to the sheet never changes once a job is in there.[Image of sheet currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPnj2.png)
In the image; job 22,484 on row 4 would have due date updated to 10/5/22 and job data on row 5 would be removed.
For each day's raw data there will be 20-25 duplicate entries.

The maximum rows used will be 5000 so the script can be inefficient if necessary.

Thanks! Connor

Here's [a link to dummy sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TkPm6J__cHY_GORFB5HyteVm-RnmDOuPrm9z-4fK82U/edit?usp=sharing)! (Thanks Mike)

Comment: People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you. You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with. By doing so, people will be more eager to help out.;

Comment: @MikeSteelson dummy sheet added :)

Comment: You explained it very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`YOUR_SHEET`)
  
  let data = sheet.getRange(`B2:M`)
                  .getDisplayValues()
                  .filter(row => row.every(cell => cell.length))

  const duplicates = [...new Set(data.flatMap(i => i[1]))].map(i => data.filter(item => item[1] === i))
                                                          .filter(i => i.length > 1)
                                                          .map(i => i[i.length-1])

  duplicates.forEach(i => {
    const removeRow = data.splice(data.findIndex(item => item === i), 1)
    data[data.findIndex(item => item[1] === i[1])] = removeRow.flat()
  })

  sheet.getRange(`B2:M`).clear()
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)

}
```

This will get all non-empty rows of table data, find the duplicates, and replace the previous(old) entries with the new data.

Let me know if this works for you!

### Commented:

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`YOUR_SHEET`)

  // Get the target range..
  let data = sheet.getRange(`B2:M`)
                  // As text.. (Avoids date issues)
                  .getDisplayValues() 
                  // ...and ignore blank rows.
                  .filter(row => row.every(cell => cell.length))

  // Get all unique `Job No`'s and replace their value in this array with the relevant rows from 'data'...
  const duplicates = [...new Set(data.flatMap(i => i[1]))].map(i => data.filter(item => item[1] === i))
                                                          // Keep all `Job No`'s rows with more than 1 entry..
                                                          .filter(i => i.length > 1)
                                                          // ...And keep only the most recent.
                                                          .map(i => i[i.length-1])

  // For each of these duplicates..
  duplicates.forEach(i => {
    // Remove the 'new' row..
    const removeRow = data.splice(data.findIndex(item => item === i), 1)
    // Replace the 'old' row..
    data[data.findIndex(item => item[1] === i[1])] = removeRow.flat()
  })

  sheet.getRange(`B2:M`).clear()
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The code above is updating the old rows with the new data but it isn't removing the new rows after doing that! And another thing I am finding is if the new jobs aren't pasted in the same order that they were the day before then it won't update the old rows either! You can test this by adding one row of data to row 6 with the job number "22457", the original data on row 3 doesn't get updated. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: In hindsight, the range is not being cleared before the values are set in the last line, which would give the appearance of the new rows not being removed. The order of the jobs don't matter, as the code works by getting a unique list of all job numbers and looping over them, retrieving all jobs with the matching number. Unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Update to include `range.clear()`

Comment: I see what you mean about the appearance of not removing the new rows because that space is not needed to fill the updated range until probably the following day of data is added, thanks for adding the .clear() , that makes a lot more sense in my head now..

Comment: Although I have tried again with the issue about jobs not being in the same order and it is still not working out for me.. I tested it with a range of dummy data and I then copied this range directly underneath (leaving a few rows blank), but then moved the top 5 rows of the copied data to the bottom of the new range and sure enough the first 5 rows didn't update when the function is run.  [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sR2jCtw3PGnZ5kmwIITBSFPx-N-2hRbOsk8Iv4HlVsU/edit?usp=sharing) dummy sheet set up as I described just then, and you may see what I'm describing? Thx :)

Comment: Just updated the dummy sheet so basically all the jobs should update to have a due date of 01/01/2023 when the function runs but as you can see the top 5 jobs don't get updated for some reason? EDIT: Function working correctly I had not implemented it correctly in my Apps Script!! Thank you NEWAZA legend :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove Dupes

```
function removeDupsOnColC() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(`DEBUG`)
  let data = sh.getRange(`B2:M` + sh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  let ua = [];
  let oA = [];
  data.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!~ua.indexOf(r[2])) {
      ua.push(r[2]);
      oA.push(r);
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2, 2, oa.length, oa[0].length).setValues(oa)
}
```